# how to find the docstring in the numpy.random module?

Tags: python, docstring

I try to find the docstring of the `numpy.random.random()` function in `vscode`. To do this  i can keep navigating to the definition using `go to definition` from the menu or by pressing the `f12` key.

...but i end up navigating to this line of code:

```
    def random(self, size: None = ...) -> float: ...  # type: ignore[misc]
```

Not only do i not find the docstring, but i dont understand what the elipses (three dots `...`) do or what this line of code means. There are various explanations of elipses for use in arrays in numpy, but not for functions or how i can navigate to the docstring from this.

So, **where is the docstring of the function** ?
(ie. the same docstring that i would see by hovering over the function)

Comment: The docstring for `numpy.random.random` is found in `numpy.random.random.__doc__`. I don't think that's what you actually wanted to know; I suspect your question is, "how can I get vscode to show me `numpy.random.random`'s signature?", or maybe, "how can I interpret the signature for `numpy.random.random` which vscode shows me?". Note that `numpy.random.random` is a compiled function written in Cython, and it's signature is not available for reflection. That's what `...` means in this context.

Comment: You can find the official documentation at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random.html. In this case, that's just an HTML formatted version of `numpy.random.random.__doc__`, which is roughly what `help(numpy.random.random)` would show you in the Python REPL.

Comment: @rici, excellent comment. It is useful to know, that it `python` / `numpy` works this way. So i will summarise by saying that if a user wants to find the docs for `Cython` based functions, then they have to search the web / docs and **not** navigate python modules...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "navigate python modules". As I said, the docstring is available in the function object itself, `numpy.random.random.__doc__`. Is that not a form of navigation? However, a given IDE (vscode, in this case) might not show you that string, which is a different issue. So the docstring is there. What you cannot get from `random` is its signature, because not all compiled functions make their signature available for reflection.

Comment: Cython is just an instance of the problem. `math.log` (which is written in C), also hides its signature, although most `math` module functions work fine. See `inspect.signature.  for the actual reflection methods, if you're interested.